# OLLVM in ndk failed when compile with bcf

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I added OLLVM to obfuscate my C++ code in Android.

These are the used parameters in `Android.mk` makefile:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -mllvm -sub -mllvm -fla -mllvm -bcf
```

but when I run `ndk-build`, the command hangs and has no effect.
Then I removed the `-bcf` option:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -mllvm -sub -mllvm -fla
```

and this time it worked.

Who can tell me what to do?

Comment: How much did you wait?

Comment: About 2 minutes